# Text width align like \hfill

Tags: alignment

Can I align some text automaticaly by defined width like this, use only text string as input?
[image: Wished output]

For example, using text "Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents", I can produce this:

[image]

using code:

```
\parbox{\textwidth-25mm}{
\bf Theoretical \hfill bases \hfill of \hfill the \hfill organization
\hfill of \hfill work \hfill with \hfill documents
 }
```

But I needed to manually place `\hfill`. Can I write a command or a macro to reproduce this result like this.

```
\somecommand{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\makebox[.75\textwidth][s]{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}

\makebox[.8\textwidth][s]{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}

\makebox[.85\textwidth][s]{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}

\makebox[.9\textwidth][s]{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}

\makebox[.95\textwidth][s]{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}

\makebox[\textwidth][s]{Theoretical bases of the organization of work with documents}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```